# Having trouble inserting a node before another node in a linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm attempting to alphabetize a linked list as I insert into it (from a file) - I currently have three checks (I'll be using this to explain my logic - if someone has a better idea, please let me know, I've been pulling my hair out over this for the entire day):

If the word grabbed from the file matches the word in the current node, simply increment the frequency counter in the node (don't bother creating a new node).  If the word comes before the current node, point previous->next to the newly created node, and point new_node->next to current node.  If the word comes after the current node, point the new node to current_node->next, then set current_node->next to the new_node.

My problem is that when I try to run this program and use a file where the second word in the file comes BEFORE the first word, and try to print the linked list, I get locked in an infinite loop - I've narrowed down the issue to the fact that somewhere, a node pointer isn't getting updated, but I don't know where, and I'm at my wit's end.

I'll attach the two files that I have, if anyone could help me, I'd really appreciate it. (There are a few debugging lines in there that aren't really necessary, I was using them to attempt to figure out where the problem was.)

**most_freq.h**

```
#ifndef MOST_FREQ_H_
#define MOST_FREQ_H_

#include <stdio.h>

//used to hold each "word" in the list
typedef struct word_node
{
char *word;
unsigned int freq; //frequency of word 
struct word_node *next;
} word_node;

struct node *readStringList(FILE *infile);

int readLine(FILE *infile, char * line_buffer);

struct node *getMostFrequent(struct word_node *head, unsigned int num_to_select);

void printStringList(struct word_node *head);

void freeStringList(struct word_node *head);

#endif
```

**most_freq.c**

```
#include "most_freq.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


/* TODO

0. Check if item is in list (make all strings lowercase)
1a. if not, insert into list
1b. if it is, increment counter for struct */

struct word_node *head = NULL; //unchanging head node
char* str_buffer = NULL;

struct node *readStringList(FILE *infile) {
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    char* tmp_buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * 255);
    while(readLine(infile, tmp_buffer) == 1) {
        if(head == NULL) { //if the linked list is empty
            //allocate space for node
            head = (word_node*) malloc (sizeof(word_node));

            //set as head node
            str_buffer[ strlen(str_buffer) - 1 ] = '\0';
            head->word = str_buffer; //set string of node to str_buffer
            head->freq = 1; //set frequency to 0
            head->next = NULL; //since we're at the first item of the list there is no next
        }
        else { //else, there is already a node in the list
            printf("Linked list has a node.\n\n");
            struct word_node *curr = head; //set curr to head (for traversal)
            struct word_node *prev = head; //to keep track of the last node
            while(curr != NULL) {   //while current is not null, continue traversal
                /* If string buffer matches current node's word, then simply update the frequency count */
                if(strcmp(str_buffer,curr->word) == 0) { //if word matches the word in the list
                    curr->freq++; //update the current node's frequency
                    break;
                }
                /* If string buffer comes after current word (in alphabet) then point temp node->next to current->next, and point current node->next to temp */
                else if(strcmp(str_buffer,curr->word) > 1) {
                    printf("Word comes after current node.\n");
                    word_node* temp = (word_node*) malloc (sizeof(word_node)); //allocate node for current str_buffer
                    temp->word = str_buffer;
                    temp->next = curr->next; //set temp node->next to current node's next
                    curr->next = temp; //set current->next to point to newly inserted node
                }
                else { //otherwise, str_buffer must come before current node
                    printf("Word comes before current node.\n");
                    word_node* temp = (word_node*) malloc (sizeof(word_node)); //allocate node for current str_buffer
                    temp->word = str_buffer;
                    printf("Previous Node: %s\n", prev->word);
                    printf("Current Node: %s\n", curr->word);
                    prev->next = temp;
                    temp->next = curr;
                }
                prev = curr;
                curr = curr->next; //move current node up by one
            }
        }
    }
    printStringList(head);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int readLine(FILE *infile, char * line_buffer) {
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, infile)) != -1) {
        line_buffer = line;
        str_buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(line));
        strncpy(str_buffer, line_buffer, strlen(line));
        if(str_buffer[0] != '\0') {
            return 1;
        }
        else
            return -1;
    }
}

void printStringList(struct word_node *top) {
    struct word_node *curr = top; //set curr to head (for traversal)
    printf("List of Strings (and Frequencies)\n\n");
    int count = 0;
    while(curr != NULL) {
        printf("%s (Frequency: %d)\n", curr->word, curr->freq);
        curr = curr->next;
        count++;
    }
    return;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *file = fopen( argv[1], "r" );

    /* fopen returns 0, the NULL pointer, on failure */
    if ( file == 0 )
    {
        printf( "Could not open file.\n" );
    }
    else
    {
        readStringList(file);
    }   
}
```

**test text file** (passed in as a parameter when running from terminal)

```
foofoo
dog
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     else { //otherwise, str_buffer must come before current node
                ....
                prev->next = temp;
                temp->next = curr;
```

If the list has only one node then `curr` and `prev` point to the same node and you are introducing a loop here.Initially you are setting both `prev` and `curr` as `head`.You should set `prev` as `NULL` initially and then handle the case if the new node is going to become the first node(when `prev` will be `NULL`)

```
     str_buffer[ strlen(str_buffer) - 1 ] = '\0';
     head->word = str_buffer; //set string of node to str_buffer
```

Also you are allocating memory for `temp_buffer` and using `str_buffer` which is just a pointer.You might want to use `temp_buffer` here.

Answer (score 0):

In this part:

```
            else { //otherwise, str_buffer must come before current node
                printf("Word comes before current node.\n");
                word_node* temp = (word_node*) malloc (sizeof(word_node)); //allocate node for current str_buffer
                temp->word = str_buffer;
                printf("Previous Node: %s\n", prev->word);
                printf("Current Node: %s\n", curr->word);
                prev->next = temp;
                temp->next = curr;
            }
```

you need to add a check for `curr == head` (or `curr == prev`). That case will require special treatment as you need to update `head`.

Otherwise you get an endless loop. In that case your current code actually do:

```
 head->next = newnode;
 newnode->next = head;
```

which makes the list circular (and an endless loop while printing).

You need something like:

```
if (curr == head)
{
    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;
    ....
}
else
{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that you need to handle adding to the front as a special case to update your `head` pointer, I find the memory allocation in your `readLine` routine confusing:

```
char* str_buffer = NULL;                                    // 1
struct node *readStringList(FILE *infile) {
    [...]
    char* tmp_buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * 255);  // 2
    while(readLine(infile, tmp_buffer) == 1) {              // 3

int readLine(FILE *infile, char * line_buffer) {
    char * line = NULL;
    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, infile)) != -1) {   // 4
        line_buffer = line;                                 // 5
        str_buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(line));         // 6
        strncpy(str_buffer, line_buffer, strlen(line));     // 7
```

You're doing three (3) memory allocations for each line read here, there's one done by `getline` at [4], since you passed in a `NULL`, another in `readLine` at [6], and a third one in `readStringList` at [2]. The `tmp_buffer` ([2]) isn't used anywhere in `readStringList` and neither does `readLine` use the respective argument (the pointer is just overwritten at [5]).

Also, there's no need to use a global variable here [1], your functions should use their arguments to pass the data (and have those arguments already).

Since you use `getline`, you can just return the buffer allocated by it to the outer function, and use it there directly.

Something like this:

```
int readLine(FILE *infile, char **line_buffer) {
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, infile)) != -1) {
        *line_buffer = line;
        if(read == 0 || read == -1)
            return -1;

        return 1;
    }
}

struct node *readStringList(FILE *infile) {
    char* str_buffer;
    while(readLine(infile, &str_buffer) == 1) {
        // do something with str_buffer
        // though remember to save it somewhere, you need to free() it later
    }
    [...]
```